# Big O of backtracking solution counts permutations with range

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, backtracking

I have a problem and I've been struggling with my solution time and space complexity:

Given an array of integers (possible duplicates) `A` and `min`, `low`, `high` are integers.
Find the total number of combinations of items in `A` that:

- `low <= A[i] <= high`
- Each combination has at least `min` numbers.
- Numbers in one combination can be duplicates as they're considered unique in A but combinations can not be duplicates. E.g.: `[1,1,2]` -> combinations: `[1,1],[1,2],[1,1,2]` are ok but `[1,1],[1,1], [1,2], [2,1] ...` are not.

Example: `A=[4, 6, 3, 13, 5, 10], min = 2, low = 3, high = 5`

There are 4 ways to combine valid integers in A: `[4,3],[4,5],[4,3,5],[3,5]`

Here's my solution and it works:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_result(self, arr, min_size, low, high):
        return self._count_ways(arr, min_size, low, high, 0, 0)
    def _count_ways(self, arr, min_size, low, high, idx, comb_size):
        if idx == len(arr):
            return 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(idx, len(arr)):
            if arr[i] >= low and arr[i] <= high:
                comb_size += 1
                if comb_size >= min_size:
                    count += 1
                count += self._count_ways(arr, min_size, low, high, i + 1, comb_size)
                comb_size -= 1
        return count
```

I use backtracking so:

Time: `O(n!)` because for every single integer, I check with each and every single remaining one in worst case - when all integers can form combinations.

Space: `O(n)` for at most I need n calls on the call stack and I only use 2 variables to keep track of my combinations.

Is my analysis correct?

Also, a bit out of the scope but: Should I do some kind of memoization to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, your algorithm is far too complicated. You can do it as follows:

1. Compute array `B` containing all elements in `A` between `low` and `high`.
2. Return `sum of Choose(B.length, k)` for `k = min .. B.length`, where `Choose(n,k)` is `n(n-1)..(n-k+1)/k!`.

Time and space complexities are `O(n)` if you use memoization to compute the numerators/denominators of the `Choose` function (e.g. if you have already computed `5*4*3`, you only need one multiplication to compute `5*4*3*2` etc.).

In your example, you would get `B = [4, 3, 5]`, so `B.length = 3`, and the result is

```
  Choose(3, 2) + Choose(3, 3) 
= (3 * 2)/(2 * 1) + (3 * 2 * 1)/(3 * 2 * 1) 
= 3 + 1
= 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to do `O(n)` to get the numbers between `low` and `high` but I wasn't able to figure out the 2nd step. I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can find a technique to figure out the formula you wrote?

Comment: @Viet Sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Thank you Mo. That's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of the time complexity isn't quite right.

I understand where you're getting `O(n!)`: the `for i in range(idx, len(arr)):` loop decreases in length with every recursive call, so it seems like you're doing `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...`.

However, the recursive calls from a loop of length `m` do not always contain a loop of size `m-1`. Suppose your outermost call has 3 elements. The loop iterates through 3 possible values, each spawning a new call. The first such call will have a loop that iterates over 2 values, but the next call iterates over only 1 value, and the last immediately hits your base case and stops. So instead of `3*2*1=((1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1))`, you get `((1+0)+1+0)`.

A call to `_count_ways` with an array of size `n` takes twice as long as a call with size `n-1`. To see this, consider the first branch in the call of size `n` which is to choose the first element or not. First we choose that first element, which leads to a recursive call with size `n-1`. Second we do not choose that first element, which gives us `n-1` elements left to iterate over, so it's as if we had a second recursive call with size `n-1`.

Each increase in n increase time complexity by a factor of 2, so the time complexity of your solution is `O(2^n)`. This makes sense: you're checking every combination, and there are `2^n` combinations in a set of size `n`.

However, as you're only trying to count the combinations and not do something with them, this is highly inefficient. See @Mo B.'s answer for a better solution.